# is there any way to resolve this animated error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi when I try start the project on simulator I get this error and I don't know how to solve it. I have been searching and cloud not find it who had some problem. it gives me this error ''export * as default from './Animated';'' [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhkcr.png)

anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from plugin